# Python: Call function that returns two strings inside map function

Tags: python, map-function

Hello I am trying to create a function that is called inside a map function, splits the string that have been passed as input and returns two processed strings. To be more understood here is my code (it doesn't seem to return anything).

```
def prepare_data(data):
    x1, x2 = data.split(" ", 1) # split only 1 time at the space
    return x1.strip("\""), x2 



if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(list(map(prepare_data, '"word_1" rest of sentence')))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You are mapping the function `prepare_data` for each character of the string

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is actually a tuple that contains (word1, rest of sentence)

Comment: @C96 Then, it's just `print(prepare_data('"word_1" rest of sentence'))`.

Comment: Yeah that is the obvious solution but I have to do it with map

Comment: @C96 Why do you have to use map? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Pass map a list of sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an iterable List from your sentence. Use:

```
x = map(prepare_data, ['"word_1" rest of sentence'])

print(list(x))
```

Comment: map expects a list to iterate over.

Comment: @Malo is exactly correct. The string is an iterable but you need to pass the whole object to your function hence it has to be a one-element List which is iterated to produce the string. This is clear if you try  `x = map(prepare_data, ['"word_1" rest of sentence', 'test1 test2'])`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe the split function returns a list which cannot be unpacked into two variables. So its better to unpack it into a variable and return the elements in the list

Comment: What do you mean, "a list cannot be unpacked into two variables"? Of course it can

Comment: it would be safer into a variable in case number of elements is different than 2.

Comment: @Malo [`str.split(" ", 1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) can return exactly one or two items. It'll never return more, and in the asker's case if it returns one, that means the string is not in the format specified. When you're passed invalid data, an exception is probably not an unreasonable result.

Comment: @CrazyChucky  ok so it is satfer if the split does not works (0 split). Yes an exception / error is to be expected, but over the OP question.